# UILabel in UITableViewCell to make a customised cell without making separate class

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray

In my table view cell i need to display the contents of my array elements in a single cell and if i insert any new contents the previous contents are not to be overwritten.The previous content and my new content should be displayed in order.Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];




NSMutableArray *arrMain=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: cnfqty, cnftitle, cnfrate, nil];

finarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[finarray addObjectsFromArray:arrMain];
   NSLog(@"%@",finarray);


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }

 #pragma mark - Table view data source

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

return 150.0;

 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
 // Return the number of rows in the section.
return ( [finarray count] / 3 ); 
}


 - (UITableViewCell *) getCellContentView:(NSString *)cellIdentifier {

UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

UILabel *tempLabel;
//UIImage *tempImage;

/* Create UI elements - Customize as you want your text to appear */

CGRect myFirstLabel = CGRectMake (65, 10, 200, 15);
CGRect mySecondLabel = CGRectMake (65, 25, 200, 15);
CGRect myThirdLabel = CGRectMake (65, 40, 200, 15);
 //  CGRect myImage = CGRectMake (10, 10, 50, 50);

//Initialize first label
tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: myFirstLabel];
tempLabel.tag = 1;
tempLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview: tempLabel];

//Initialize second label
tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: mySecondLabel];
tempLabel.tag = 2;
tempLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview: tempLabel];

//Initialize third label
tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: myThirdLabel];
tempLabel.tag = 3;
tempLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview: tempLabel];

//Initialize your picture
//imgTemp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: myImage];
//imgTemp.tag = 4;
//[cell.contentView addSubview: tempImage];

return cell;
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"aCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [self getCellContentView: CellIdentifier];
}

//This will create the actual UI elements
UILabel *tempLabel1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag: 1];
UILabel *tempLabel2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag: 2];
UILabel *tempLabel3 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag: 3];
//UIImageView *tempImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag: 4];

// Populate the labels
NSString *firstText = [NSString stringWithString: [finarray objectAtIndex: 3*(indexPath.row)]];
NSString *secondText = [NSString stringWithString: [finarray objectAtIndex: 3*(indexPath.row) + 1]];
NSString *thirdText = [NSString stringWithString: [finarray objectAtIndex: 3*(indexPath.row) + 2]];

// Populate the picture
//UIImage *picture = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:theObjectToPutInCell.picture];

tempLabel1.text = firstText;
tempLabel2.text = secondText;
tempLabel3.text = thirdText;

 // tempImage.image = picture;

return cell;  


}
}

@end
```

The problem which i'm facing with my code is each string is displayed in each cell and if i insert any new string previous contents are gone and only new contents are displayed.

To get clear idea about this question i'm trying to implement "add to cart" service for online shopping.As per concept the items have to be added from various products and it saves the product info and have to display the details in Table view.But i'm not getting it..

Kindly Guide please..Thanks in advance..

My output is like this first image

[image]

But i need to get display as second image which done in Android..
[image]

Comment: Hi, can you post the log you get with "NSLog(@"%@",fin array);" ?

Comment: it displays like this    2012-07-26 16:39:42.729 tablevc[1982:f803] (
        (
        2
    ),
        (
        "BOLLYWOOD DREAMS VOL3 3001"
    ),
        (
        "358.000000"
    )
)

Comment: You have a real bug - you try to recycle cells, but regardless of whether you get one or not you overwrite the cell with a newly created cell

Comment: Can u explain where is have bug in my code

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

Comment: Please don't ask a new question in the bounty notice.  If you have a new question (not just a minor extension of this) then ask a new question.

Comment: And please re-accept the answer that solved your initial problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got it by following code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"aCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
UILabel *label1=[[UILabel alloc]init];
label1.frame=.....;
................
[cell.contentView addSubView: label1];

UILabel *label2=[[UILabel alloc]init];
label2.frame=.....;
................
[cell.contentView addSubView: label2];

UILabel *label3=[[UILabel alloc]init];
label3.frame=.....;
................
[cell.contentView addSubView: label3];
}
```

The text to the labels are assigned from individual Array element like this

```
NSMutableArray *label1Array=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"",nil];
NSMutableArray *label2Array=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"",nil];
NSMutableArray *label3Array=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"",nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is something you can try :

Create a function like this one to create all the graphic elements needed :

```
// Cell appearence editing
- (UITableViewCell *) getCellContentView:(NSString *)cellIdentifier {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    UILabel *tempLabel;
    UIImage *tempImage;

    /* Create UI elements - Customize as you want your text to appear */

    CGRect myFirstLabel = CGRectMake (65, 10, 200, 15);
    CGRect mySecondLabel = CGRectMake (65, 25, 200, 15);
    CGRect myThirdLabel = CGRectMake (65, 40, 200, 15);
    CGRect myImage = CGRectMake (10, 10, 50, 50);

    //Initialize first label
    tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: myFirstLabel];
    tempLabel.tag = 1;
    tempLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: tempLabel];

    //Initialize second label
    tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: mySecondLabel];
    tempLabel.tag = 2;
    tempLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: tempLabel];

    //Initialize third label
    tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: mySecondLabel];
    tempLabel.tag = 3;
    tempLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: tempLabel];

    //Initialize your picture
    imgTemp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: myImage];
    imgTemp.tag = 4;
    [cell.contentView addSubview: tempImage];

    return cell;
}
```

Then, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, call the "design function" and populate it with your content :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"aCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [self getCellContentView: CellIdentifier];
    }

    //This will create the actual UI elements
    UILabel *tempLabel1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag: 1];
    UILabel *tempLabel2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag: 2];
    UILabel *tempLabel3 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag: 3];
    UIImageView *tempImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag: 4];

    // Populate the labels
    NSString *firstText = [NSString stringWithString: [finarray stringAtIndex: 3*(indexPath.row)]];
    NSString *secondText = [NSString stringWithString: [finarray stringAtIndex: 3*(indexPath.row) + 1]];
    NSString *thirdText = [NSString stringWithString: [finarray stringAtIndex: 3*(indexPath.row) + 2]];

    // Populate the picture
    UIImage *picture = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:theObjectToPutInCell.picture];

    tempLabel1.text = firstText;
    tempLabel2.text = secondText;
    tempLabel3.text = thirdText;

    tempImage.image = picture;

    return cell;

}
```

Let me know if it helps !

Comment: Shall i replace it my object as NSObject and first field,second field,third field,ligneTableau2;
ligneTableau3;
ligneTableau4; shows error...

Comment: I updated the code for the "ligneTableauX" errors (sorry, bad copy/paste from my own code).

Comment: I also fixed the NSObject error in the "//populate the labels" paragraph. What do you put in your array ? NSStrings ? If you add an other object to the cart, what is the NSLog ?

Comment: I'm inserting 3 NSstrings and if i add another 3 new values only my new values gets printed and previous contents not displayed..I get a reference if we use reload data we can retrieve the old contents and display the contents like the image which i attached how in android looks...

Comment: I re-edited my answer, considering that you put your elements in your array with NSStrings, like this : (product1Quantity, product1Description, product1Price, product2Quantity, product2Description, product2Price, product3Quantity, ...).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14462/discussion-between-rdurand-and-user1186914)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [itemsData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row] ;
    UILabel *lblTitle = nil;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;




        lblTitle =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 15, 110, 44)];
        lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        lblTitle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0];
        lblTitle.tag = 1;
        lblTitle.numberOfLines = 0;


        UILabel *lblType =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 0, 75, 44)];
        lblType.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblType.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        lblType.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0];
        lblType.tag = 2;

        UILabel *lblDate =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 60, 44)];
        lblDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblDate.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        lblDate.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0];
        lblDate.tag = 3;

        UILabel *lblTime =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(265, 0, 50, 44)];
        lblTime.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblTime.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        lblTime.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0];
        lblTime.tag = 4;

        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView endUpdates]; 
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTitle];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblType];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblDate];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTime];

    }

NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@",[[itemsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"address"],[[itemsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"],[[itemsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"zipcode"]];


    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];

    if (!lblTitle)
        lblTitle = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    [lblTitle setText:text];
    [lblTitle setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), MAX(size.height, 44.0f))];


    UILabel *lblType = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    lblType.text =[[itemsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"type"];

    UILabel *lblDate = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
    lblDate.text =[[itemsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];

    UILabel *lblTime = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
    lblTime.text =[[itemsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"time"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: first of all add your new data and reload your table.

Comment: Into your cell count is one because you set [finarray count] / 3.You add three objects into array and use it.

Comment: I spent some time solving your display problem with you. The fact that you don't manage your NSMutableArray properly is a new problem and does not suit in this thread. Please accept the answer correcting your initial problem (displaying the infos in the right place), and ask a new question.