# How to save data from different view controllers and load it in another view controllers in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I'm new to iOS. After going through a lot of and documents i'm confused .This is what I have to do.

I have several view controllers each has NSString values which I'll enter in a textfield and save it in a common place and when I need to view the data, it would be displayed in a`UITableview`. I know how to create a `UITableview` and load the data in it. But I have to know how to save and load that.

So far I have tried somethings . If I enter a new field, the old contents are overwritten.I don't know where to start..Can anyone give me step by step logic(not code). So that I can follow that.

I tried using NSdefaults but its not efficient as i expected

Comment: I think u want to stroe your data in DB(SQlite) right?

Comment: even after app exits and relaunched not reinstalled the data have to be stored.Which is the best way?.

Comment: Strore required data in your local DB then fetch when it' require.

Comment: you can refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669766/contents-in-the-uitableviewcell-are-not-displayed-after-inserting-new-contents-i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save the data in multiple ways

1. Use CoreData to save the data. You will find some good tuts on how to use CoreData
2. Use an SQLite database without CoreData
3. Save data into your app delegate or a view controller accessible from the final view controller
4. Pass the data from all viewcontrollers to the final viewcontroller
5. Save data in a plist

The possibilities are endless. What works best for your project is what you should use.

Comment: you can refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669766/contents-in-the-uitableviewcell-are-not-displayed-after-inserting-new-contents-i...

Comment: To keep the data saved even after the app exits, you can use 1, 2 and 5

Comment: Singleton pattern would also facilitates to store values like appdelegate

Answer (score 2):

1-you can save common data with your app delegate interface . then you can access it from others interfaces

2-you can use NSUserDefault to store data with keys

3-create NSString object and with passing from view to another one pass data to new NSString object

Answer (score 1):

There are two options available storing and retrieving data in different view controllers.

1)NSUserDefaults is best option for storing data and accessing in any other view controllers.

The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as float, double, integer, Boolean. A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.

This is very easy and best method for storing and retrieving data.

if you want to read about NSUserDefaults, here i am sharing document.

```
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html
```

2) You would create properties when you want them to be accessible outside the class or other view controllers.

Create property in this way. `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arrayData;` and then you can use this array value in other view controllers also.

Properties replace the accessor methods for objects.

Answer (score 1):

using a db is better choice here. But if you want those data only dynamically then u can save it in a array and get those common data by delegates.