# How to pass date values to another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am able to pass integer values on to another class, but what about dates? I am using the following code to pass integers on:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toStep2"]) {
        Step2ViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSLog(@"text : %@",self.wrp.text);
        //This is the id infoRequest, which is a pointer to the object
        //Look at the viewDidLoad in the Destination implementation.
        detailViewController.infoRequest = self.wrp.text;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the user enters a date with a UIDatePicker in my Step1 class, but how can  the date be passed to the Step2 class? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply declare another NSDate property in Step2ViewController, and set it just like you set the infoRequest

Comment: I did, but now I am getting an error: "Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSDate *_strong' from 'NSString *'"

Answer (score 0):

You can take a property of type date in step2 class ( @property(nonatomic, retain) NSDate *step2Date;).  While transitioning to step2 class assign the datePicker value to  date property in step2 class.

step2ClassObject.step2Date = datePicker.date;

Answer (score 0):

Since UIStoryboardSegue provides both sourceViewController and destinationViewController you can take any values from properties stored in a source and put the to the properties in destination. Using a NSUserDefaults for transferring the date between controllers is not the best option since it will be stored between sessions on flash and it is actually was not build for such purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Create one NSDate property in Step2ViewController and set UIDatePicker date in Step1 class for that Step2 date instance.

Use this link for more details:

http://www.scott-sherwood.com/ios-5-storyboards/

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:lastUpdated forKey:@"dateUpdated"];
```

to store date and you can use that in next class using:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dateUpdated"];
```

For more detail revert me

Comment: It is a bad style of programming to do internal communications through the NSUserDefaults. It will cause unnecessary I/O and energy consumption as well as additional flash space.

Answer (score -1):

You would create properties when you want them to be accessible outside the class or other view controllers.

Create property in this way. @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strData; and then you can use this array value in other view controllers also.

Properties replace the accessor methods for objects.

With reference from this question's answer [my asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718632/how-to-save-data-from-different-view-controllers-and-load-it-in-another-view-con/14208947#14208947)

Comment: Guys are you seriously suggest to use NSUserDefaults to passing values between classes? Looks like IT industry in troubles...

Comment: I have given two options which one feasible and meets your requirement you can use.